# How do I make an option page in a Chrome (non-legacy) packaged app?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app, chrome-options

Some time ago, there were still Chrome-packaged legacy apps which could make options-pages. I want to use the option-page in my Chrome app, but when I try to use it, the extension page shows:

*''options_page' is only allowed for extensions, hosted apps, and legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app'*.

How can I use an options-page or something of the kind to store and read settings for my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message above, you need to create an "option page" by yourself for the Chrome Apps. Also, you can use following features to store each value for the "option page":

- [chrome.storage.sync](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#property-sync)
- [chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#property-local)
- [HTML5 Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)
- Storing each value into your backend server via Ajax
- Other solutions...

That is, you should implement the feature for providing the "option page" by yourself, including a page creation, each event handling and storing each setting value.